# Java - How to choose what subclass to construct

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, extends

I have a parent class:

```
public class Animal {
  public Animal(String name, AnimalTypeEnum type) {
  }
}
```

I have **lots** (in the case that has caused me to make this over 30) children:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog(String name, AnimalTypeEnum type) {
    super(name,type);
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat(String name, AnimalTypeEnum type) {
    super(name,type);
  }
}
```

The objects are constructed from many different places in the project (loaded on start up, created at various times in runtime. To "create" an object, I currently use this function (over 30 subclasses in the project, not just 2):

```
public static Animal create(String name, AnimalTypeEnum type) {
  switch(type) {
    case DOG:
      return new Dog(name, type);
    case CAT:
      return new Cat(name, type);
  }
}
```

It is important to note that none of the subclasses have any difference in parameters. The reason I'm using subclasses is because they have one or two functions that are overriden.

Say I now wanted to add a parameter for all subclasses, I'd need to:

- Add the parameter to the `Animal` constructor
- Add the parameter to the subclass constructors
- Add the parameter to the `create()` function
- (also change the parameter wherever the `create()` function is being called)

Ideally, I'd like to eliminate changing the subclass parameters (none of the subclasses have different parameters) and the `create()` function from the above process. But if that isn't possible, I'd like to find a better alternative to the `create()` function. The best solution I've thought of (**psuedocode**) is:

```
public Animal(String name, AnimalTypeEnum type) {
  if (type == CAT) this.subclass(Cat);
  if (type == DOG) this.subclass(Dog);
}
```

I think the above goes against the principle of class inheritance so I want to be clear that this isn't the solution I am trying to find, just how I imagine a solution *could* work.

This is a rather trivial issue but I feel that bad programming practices are behind it and I would like to rectify these. My questions would be (incase I haven't properly explained my problem/reasons):

- Is inheritance even the ideal way to do this?
- Is it possible to eliminate the process of changing the constructor in subclasses in this situation?
- Is there anything I can do to remove the `create()` function, and assign the subclass when constructing `Animal`?

Thank you.

Comment: There are a collection of builder patterns addressed for your kind of problem. Please take a look into: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 2):

I think that you wonna use the Factory Pattern, so you have any options for solve your problem @Doleron showed the first one, but you can use this too:

```
public interface Animal {
   public String getName();
}
```

The implementation Dog

```
public class Dog implements  Animal{
   private String name;
   public Dog(String name) {
      this.name=name;
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

Cat

```
public class Cat implements Animal{
   private String name;
   public Cat(String name) {
       this.name=name;
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
}
```

Factory

```
public class AnimalFactory {
   /*
    * Some people use static attributs like:
    * public static final String DOG ="DOG";
    */
   public static Animal creatAnimal(String animal, String name){
     if("DOG".equalsIgnoreCase(animal)){
        return new Dog(name);

     } else if("CAT".equalsIgnoreCase(animal)){
        return new Cat(name);

     }
     return null;
   }     
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal = AnimalFactory.creatAnimal("dog", "pluto");
    /*
     * if you use static attribut you can call this form
     */
    //Animal dog = AnimalFactory.creatAnimal(AnimalFactory.DOG, "pluto");
    System.out.println("Name "+animal.getName()+ " class "+animal.getClass().getSimpleName() );

    animal = AnimalFactory.creatAnimal("cat", "garfield");

    System.out.println("Name "+animal.getName()+ " class "+animal.getClass().getSimpleName() );
}
```

you can see another example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an enum to identify the instance type, you could avoid the create/switch/if-else approach using a polymorphic enumeration like:

```
public enum AnimalTypeEnum {

    CAT {
        public Animal create(String name) {
            return new Cat(name);
        }
    },
    DOG {
        public Animal create(String name) {
            return new Dog(name);
        }
    },
    COW {
        public Animal create(String name) {
            return new Cow(name);
        }
    };

    abstract Animal create(String name);
}
```

As everything this approach has pros and cons. Please see if it fits to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast! I'm going to have a read of the wiki pages you sent me tomorrow (1AM here in the UK, too tired to take it all in).I think a builder is the best approach to this issue because as long as I have a constructor that will change, I'll need to update the super for every subclass.

Comment: Nice. This book https://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Workbook-Steven-Metsker/dp/0201743973 is an improvement over the seminal "Gang of Four" book about design patterns. It is very desirable to read it to improve the understand how to assign responsibilities over classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the base class Animal should be an *abstract* class, because you'll never give life to an Animal object but to a more specific type of Animal, i.e Dog, Cat et cetera. In this way, all animals will have some base methods already implemented.However, if some subclass needs to inherit from another class, you should consider Animal as an Interface, because Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. 
For your second question, if I correctly understand, why can't you add a **protected** member to the base class Animal and initialize it in the Animal costructor? Eventually, if subclasses as a specific value for this parameter, you can set it in the subclasses costructors.
Finally for the create() function in my opinion you should consider the Abstract Factory pattern.